# Minecraft 1.8.9 won't start on Linux

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I use Minecraft: Java Edition on a Linux system. Whenever I try to launch versions 1.8.9 and before, the doesn't start, and as soon as I hit the "Play" button, the Launcher re-opens stating that the game has crashed. The game runs perfectly if I play it in earlier versions.

I was able to generate a crash report by enabling "Open output log when games start" in the Settings menu. It's a bit lengthy, so I made a Pastebin for it... https://pastebin.com/KN2Ac9vb

I would like to know what's going wrong, and how to fix this error so I can play 1.8.9 properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55847497/how-do-i-troubleshoot-inconsistency-detected-dl-lookup-c-111-java-result-12), this is due to an issue in your Java install. Grabbing an earlier version of (or even just reinstalling) Java should fix it. Alternate JDKs may also work.